# Добавление изображений из dropzone в БД

Tags: javascript, php, phpmyadmin, php7

Как добавить путь к картинкам в БД?

```
<h3>Галерея</h3>
    <div class="submit-section">
        <form action="submit-property.php"  class="dropzone" id="my-dropzone"></form>
    </div>
```

На сервер картинки загружаются,а в БД нет.

```
    <?php
        $ds= DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR; 
         
        $storeFolder = 'user_data';  
         
        if (!empty($_FILES)) {
         
            $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];         
         
            $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds; 
         
            $targetFile =  $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name']; 
            
            $query=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT into images (id_room,name_image) VALUES('$id_room','$targetFile')");
               
            move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
        
        } 
?>
    
    <script src="dropzone.js"></script>
    <script>
   
    Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
        init: function() {
            thisDropzone = this;
  
            $.get('submit-property.php', function(data) {
     
       
                $.each(data, function(key,value){
                     
                    var mockFile = { name: value.name, size: value.size };
                     
                    thisDropzone.options.addedfile.call(thisDropzone, mockFile);
     
                    thisDropzone.options.thumbnail.call(thisDropzone, mockFile, "user_data/"+value.name);
                     
                });
                 
            });
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: и что получается в результате этого кода в бд?

Comment: @ValeriiVasiliev город и адрес. Картинки не видит

Comment: не добавляются картинки в базу? приведите результат работы скрипта в базе

Comment: @ValeriiVasiliev Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: думаю проблема в том как Вы создаете форму. описал в ответе возможный вариант изменения

Answer (score 0):

Думаю проблема в инициализации формы

Нужно заменить

```
<form action="submit-property.php" name="files[]" multiple="" class="dropzone" enctype="multipart/form-data">
</form>
```

На

```
<form action="submit-property.php" class="dropzone" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input name="files[]" type="file" />
</form>
```

Comment: изменил код выше. Картинки на сервер теперь загружаются, но запрос на добавление в БД не выполняется

Comment: @user402416 сделайте вывод ошибки запроса и посмотрите, что не так с ним if (!mysqli_query($con,"INSERT into images (id_room,name_image) VALUES('$id_room','$targetFile')")) {
        printf("Ошибка: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
}

Comment: Ошибка: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''D:\server\OSPanel\domains\HTML\user_data\')' at line 1

Comment: @user402416 попробуйте экранировать данные в запросе через mysqli_real_escape_string